# linking, compiling and running a c program with a static library

Tags: c, cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I'm new to C development.

**A** I built a library (static) in CLion

**library.h**

```
#ifndef MYLIB_LIBRARY_H
#define MYLIB_LIBRARY_H

int add(int a, int b);
int sub(int a, int b);

#endif
```

**library.c**

```
#include "library.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int sub(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(MyLib)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SOURCE_FILES library.c library.h)
add_library(MyLib ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

---

---

**B.** Created C Executable project called App and copied `libMyLib.a` into lib directory of App.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "library.h" // error

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n", add(1, 2)); // error
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt** of the project App and specified folder for the linker.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(App)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
add_executable(App ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Question. How can I make my program work using static library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things I had to change to get your example to work:

1. Create an `include` directory in the App directory.
2. Put `library.h` in this include directory.
3. Modify the project CMakeLists.txt file:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
   project(App)

   set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
   set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
   # get libMyLib.a
   find_library(MY_LIB
       NAMES libMyLib.a
       PATHS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
   # get library.h
   include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

   add_executable(App ${SOURCE_FILES})
   # link App with libMyLib.a
   target_link_libraries(App ${MY_LIB})
   ```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I've another question, what are the conventions of distributing your library. How people expect 3rd party libraries, seems I'll distribute `.a` and `.h` files together. Also should I have placed both `libMyLib.a` and `library.h` within the include folder?

Comment: any suggestion please?

Comment: I don't have any experience distributing libraries, however, I think the convention is to have lib/ directory for `.a` and `.so` files and have an include directory for `.h` files. You might also consider adding documentation and testing for the library. Here's a link to the jsoncpp library repo which uses cmake: https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp. They actually provide the source files and header files needed to build the library and the end user is the one who builds it using cmake/make.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
printf("Hello, World!\n", add(1, 2)); // error
```

is generating an error at compile time, not link time

The reason is the `printf()` function is being passed as the first argument (the format string) `Hello, World!\n` and the second argument: `add(1,2)`  However, there is no format specifier in the format string for the results of the call to `add()`

The compiler will output the message:

```
warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

There is no reason to be looking at the Cmakelists.txt file until after correcting the compile problems

Comment: thanks eventually i fixed it after the other answer about cmake, i wanna know what's the directory structure when it comes to distributing 3rd party c libraries, and what's the convention of placing them in your project?

Comment: the simplest way is to place the libraries in a (your preference) directory, then place a link in a place that the linker will normally look, for instance in `/usr/lib/`

Comment: from cosmetic point of view, my library project prefixed my `.a` filename with `lib`, I renamed manually but compiler complained when linking. how can i configure to create .a name I like?

Comment: @User794691,  The linker has its' own rules and syntax.  It matters not what you might like, It matters what the linker likes.